# rostest xml API

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering whether how to provide gtest compatible executables in other languages than cpp and python.

I can see that adding a `<test>` node to a launch file will call the executable with at least:
`'--gtest_output=xml:.../.ros/test_results/.../TEST-test-name_test.xml'`
I'll guess support of this option is what an executable would minimally need to supply, for extended use maybe also --gtest_repeat, --gtest_filter

I assume the executable must then write an xml file containing junit-like xml the way gtest generates it.

Is there more to it than that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10841/rostest-xml-api/) by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7848 on 2011-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's basically it.

The only other additions are the CMake macros for invoking the tests if you wish to run standalone unit tests (i.e. with rosunit).  The macros are mainly a matter of convenience.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0